# ComplexHeatmap annotation seems to be missing data

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, heatmap

The following toy data set seems to exemplify the problem:

```
set.seed(0)
mm = matrix(data = rnorm(1000 * 8), nrow = 8)
rownames(mm) = letters[1:8]
annodf = data.frame(var1=rbinom(1000, 1, .01))

library(ComplexHeatmap)
ha = HeatmapAnnotation(df=annodf, col=list("var1"=c("0"="white","1"="red")))
ht = Heatmap(mm, show_column_dend = F, 
        show_column_names = F, bottom_annotation = ha)
draw(ht)
```

This is the image I see on my computer (I am using Rstudio):
[image]
I can make out 9 distinct lines in the annotation, though one of them is thicker and may be composed of multiple lines.

I can also plot the annotation separately as a barplot to see what I think it should look like using

```
barplot(annodf$var1[column_order(ht)])
```

This gives me:
[image]

This looks like 11 lines, with one probably composed of two. We can look at the data:

```
> sum(annodf$var1)
[1] 12
> which(annodf$var1[column_order(ht)]==1)
 [1] 112 126 128 250 430 477 561 568 643 673 893 934
```

to confirm that the barplot is correct.

Why does the annotation seem to be missing data?

**Update:**

I don't seem to see this discrepancy in smaller datasets. To illustrate this point, and to confirm that the method of writing the barplot of the annotation is correct, I do so for a 5x5 plot:

```
set.seed(0)
mm2 = matrix(data = rnorm(5 * 5), nrow = 5)
rownames(mm2) = letters[1:5]
colnames(mm2) = LETTERS[1:5]
annodf2 = data.frame(var1=rbinom(5, 1, .45))
ha2 = HeatmapAnnotation(df=annodf2, col=list("var1"=c("0"="white","1"="red")))
ht2 = Heatmap(mm2, show_column_dend = F, 
             show_column_names = F, bottom_annotation = ha2)
draw(ht2)
barplot(annodf2$var1[column_order(ht2)])
```

The heatmap annotation:[image], and the barplot:[image]

These match, as the 2nd and the 5th columns have var1=1. So why don't the annotation and the barplot match for the larger plot?

Crossposted: https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap/issues/142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the annotation is not drawing lines as such but filled rectangles, and with 1000 columns the drawing routines cannot draw the filled rectangles consistently (there's not enough resolution to do so). As is clear from the update to the question using a heatmap with just a small number of columns, the 'lines' drawn are filled rectangles.

Thinking it was a line issue rather than a filled rectangle problem, I investigated the use of the gp (graphics parameter) argument in the HeatmapAnnotation function to see if I could increase line width, and in doing so it became clear that it is not lines that are being drawn. For instance, here's the output of the use of gpar options to increase line width to a large value:

```
ha = HeatmapAnnotation(df=annodf, gp = gpar(col = annodf$var1[column_order(ht)], 
                                            lwd = unit(20, "native")))
```

[image]

The black lines with rounded ends are overlaid with a fill derived by the draw heatmap function itself. Additionally, the use of the gpar *fill* parameter is disallowed in the HeatmapAnnotation:

```
Error in SingleAnnotation(name = anno_name[i], value = df[, i], na_col = na_col,  : 
  You should not set `fill`.
```

Finally, you may see that in investigating this I have set the gpar colour parameter to annodf$var1[column_order(ht)], which only works after the heatmap has been populated at least once. When an attempt is made to set line width using gpar the colour of the annotation is overridden and the annotation becomes no more than a mass of lines, 1 for every column:

```
ha = HeatmapAnnotation(df=annodf, gp = gpar(lwd = unit(1, "native")))
```

[image]

So, it is not lines that are being drawn, but filled rectangles, and when there are too many columns in the dataset there is a resolution issue which prevents some of the annotated fills being visible dependent on the zoom at which the annotation is being viewed. This is true when viewing a PDF of the heatmap output as well. Being a vector format, the zoom level affects what is drawn at larger scales and reveals detail that does not show at lower zoom levels. All 12 'lines' (in reality filled rectangles) really are there:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! As it stands ComplexHeatmap will have trouble annotating large datasets. Annheatmap from Heatplus does better.

Answer (score 1):

The x-axis annotation has more than nine lines. It's just that you can't see them when viewed in smaller windows as they are too close to each other. If you zoom the viewer window far enough you will see that they are there. Better still, output your plot to PDF (so that it does not lose detail) and check the pdf version.

```
pdf("heatmap.pdf")
draw(ht)
dev.off()
```

Using the default height and width you'll see the following detail if you zoom to 150%:

[image]

Though what you see is not the same as your barplot, I can't verify the method you have used for the barplot would give the same result as in the heatmap. There are twelve distinct lines on the annotation, but without being able to see  what the x-axis scale is on your heatmap I just can't hazard a guess as to why the barplot does not match the heatmap.

Comment: Thanks! I've added the code for the barplot now: barplot(annodf$var1[column_order(ht)])